# GWT+Phonegap - File upload and download with requests that need headers and some parameters

Tags: gwt, file-upload, cordova

I'm facing a problem in the development of a GWT+Phonegap application. At some point, I want to upload media (image and sound files) that the app produces with Phonegap (from the camera, microphone, etc.) to a JackRabbit server.

The first thing I found was the FileTransfer from Phonegap, and I thought it was perfect. However, I soon realized that FileTransfer doesn't allow headers on its requests - or at least I couldn't find a way to do it. This header is my authentication, so I can't really work around that. Also, from what I understood from the API, the FileTransfer allows only one pair of parameters - I need at least 5.

What I really needed was a way to upload files that is was flexible as the GWT RequestBuilder, which I use on any other cases besides file transfers and works perfectly, but accesses transparently the device's file system as phonegap does. Does anyone know if my problem has a known solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the FileTransfer code allows you have specify as many parameters as you want. Just do this:

```
var params = new Object();
params.value1 = "test";
params.value2 = "param";
params.value3 = "third";
```

Also add you comments to:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-78

so we can find out exactly what is needed to be added for FileTransfer headers.